# What's the lexical enviroment of 'name' variable in this code?

Tags: javascript, lexical-scope

I know that lexical enviroment (LE) and context are different things. But is it correct that `this.name` has the same LE as `user` in this case (global)?

```
var user = {
  name: 'Василий',

  sayHi: function() {
    alert( this.name );
  }
};

user.sayHi();
```

Comment: No, it isn't. The duplicate question explains how `this` works.

Comment: well, it all depends how you call the function, but in this case, yes it is the `user`